# How do series connected lamp dimmers/electronic switches work?

Tags: switches, lamp

How does a series connected electronic LED lamp switch operate when it has switched the lamp off and there is no voltage reference. And how does it work when the lamp is switched on and the voltage drop on the switch is different with different power lamps?

For example: [VL-C701](https://www.livoloeurope.eu/livolo-wifi-touch-light-switch-with-glass-panel-vl-c701-11?filter=14)

Comment: You typically cannot connect AC lamp dimmers in series (an off device is of so the others can't switch on). I have seen dimmers in parallel work after a fashion but you limit the range if both are partially on. Not sure what you mean by electronic switches with LEDs ...if you mean PWM controllers then they are quite different to lamp dimmers and are almost universally a DC device and not suitable for series connection.

Answer (score 1):

> How does a series connected electronic LED lamp switch operate when it has switched the lamp off and there is no voltage reference.

Without any clue of what type of switch you have in mind I would have to say that when the switch is off nothing needs to happen. The circuit is dead.

> And how does it work when the lamp is switched on and the voltage drop on the switch is different with different power lamps?

Most dimmers provide a constant voltage at a particular setting. What changes is the current drawn by the load.

Comment: Most dimmer do not supply a constant voltage. They provide a constant phase trigger to turn on a Triac.

Comment: ... which will give a consistent output voltage waveform pretty much independent of load (the number of lamps connected). The resultant RMS voltage will remain the same for a given phase angle.

Comment: True, but I am not asking about dimming or phase-angle control.

Comment: OK. I think you need to edit your question then. It's causing some confusion in your readers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear but I’m assuming you’re asking about electronic switches/dimmers without a neutral connection, only hot and load, and how the device gets its power to operate.

When the switch is off, it actually trickles a small current through the load to get power. This current is so small that incandescent loads remain dark but it may cause problems with power-saving loads such as LEDs which may flicker or flash when off.

When the switch is fully on, it actually still dims the load very slightly by delaying the turn on a few degrees into each cycle, allowing it to receive power in that time.

Comment: Thanks, do you have more information about designing these kinds of circuits?